# How to Remove the Banner Message in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When I start PowerShell it always start with a banner like this:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading personal and system profiles took 1025ms.
>>
```

Or in other environment it start with this:

```
PowerShell v6.0.2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.
>>
```

What should I put in the profile file so that it start without the banner message?
I'm on Windows 10 64bit, using PowerShell 6.0.2.

Comment: Start PowerShell with the `-nologo` option.

Comment: @BrucePayette: How can the `-nologo` command be put in profile file?

Comment: AFAIK `-NoLogo` can only be put in the invoking command. When profiles get involved the logo is already printed to screen.

Comment: You could try adding the clear-host command to your profile, that should remove the banner after it’s been printed. Otherwise I guess you could update your PowerShell shortcuts to include -nologo. It might help for us to understand better why you want this.

Comment: Welcome to SO  @BrucePayette cheers- even after two years, nice to see you around

Comment: In case anyone sees this for Windows Terminal; set `"commandline": "powershell.exe -nologo"` in your `settings.json` (`Ctrl`+`,`)

Comment: For VSCode terminal, you put this in `settings.json` -- `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-nologo"]`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can start PowerShell with the `/nologo` argument to disable the message.

`powershell.exe /nologo`

This argument can be added to the PowerShell profile in the Windows Terminal settings.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Windows Terminal, just add `-NoLogo` parameter in the Command Line setting:

[image]

Comment: This is the cleanest solution!

Answer (score 3):

I achieve this for Windows PowerShell in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) by opening the terminal, typing `notepad $profile` (if it asks you to create the file, choose 'Yes'), and simply typing "clear" (without quotation marks) and saving the file. This command is then automatically run by PowerShell on start-up (this will require you to open a new terminal to see the changes).

Note: The banner stuff does appear briefly, but is automatically cleared as soon as the terminal finishes loading.

Note #2: I only know this to work with [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal).

If anyone knows how to remove the "Loading personal and system profiles took (n)ms." line, though, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an answer you might want to try.**

Edit your profile by going into powershell and typing:

```
notepad $profile
```

Delete everything in that file and input the following:

```
Clear-Host
```

If you want to add your own message you can also input the following below that line:

```
Write-Host "MESSAGE TEXT HERE"
```

Here's a snippet from my personal profile that clears all default banner text, then employs npm figlet with a personal message as banner art, and has a default "hacker" terminal color theme (Black background, green text).

```
Clear-Host
figlet -f "Merlin1" Powershellhell"
$host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "Black"
$host.ui.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Green"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer changes depending on where you are accessing powershell.

The general idea is to call powershell with the nologo argument (/nologo or -nologo).

In VSCode, the way I did this was by pasting `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-nologo"]`]
into my settings.JSON. Thanks to the comments for suggesting this. However this method is deprecated - use VSCode Shell profiles instead. VSCode automatically converted the deprecated command for me, but in case that is no longer working this is the code that VSCode added:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe (migrated)": {
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
        "args": [
            "-nologo"
        ]
    }
```

To do this in Windows Terminal, simply go to the Shell settings menu and add /nologo to the command line arguments.

Note that there is no need to clear the screen here. The startup time and customizability significantly increased for me by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your user's Windows Terminal settings.

```
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1abcde1a1abcd\LocalState
```

Open settings.json. Add `"commandline" : "powershell.exe -nologo"` in the profiles section, e.g.

```json
"profiles": 
    {
        "defaults": {},
        "list": 
        [
            {
                "guid": "{12a12abc-a1a1-1234-12a1-123a12ab12ab}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Windows PowerShell",
                "commandline" : "powershell.exe -nologo"
            }
        ]
    },
```